# How do inline this css 'heart' animation within a paragraph

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I've dug up some CSS code which assembles and dissembles a heart from say something like puzzle pieces. However, I'm unable to get this to display as an icon along with my HTML paragraph.

The CSS is pretty complex since it uses a lot of other positioning but can I get this inline with a quick hack or would that involve changing a lot of the CSS?

I've tried changing the orientation to inline and stuff but that doesn't seem to work.

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Grayscale Bootstrap Theme (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Lora,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin: 0 0 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: left !important;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 25px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: left;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    p {
        margin: 0 0 35px;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 1.6;
    }
}

a {
    color: #42dca3;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

a:focus {
a:hover,
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1d9b6c;
}

.light {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Verdana;
}

.navbar-custom {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    background-color: #000;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand .navbar-toggle {
    padding: 4px 6px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand .navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand .navbar-toggle:active {
    outline: 0;
}

.navbar-custom a {
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a {
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover {
    outline: 0;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:active {
    outline: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li.active {
    outline: 0;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li.active a {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}

.navbar-custom .nav li.active a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-custom {
        padding: 20px 0;
        border-bottom: 0;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        background: 0 0;
        -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse {
        padding: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
        background: #000;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {    
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {    
    0% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    50% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

.content-section {
    padding-top: 100px;
}

@media(min-width:767px) {
    .content-section {
        padding-top: 100px;
    }
}


img::selection {
    background: 0 0;
}

img::-moz-selection {
    background: 0 0;
}

body {
    webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}

.heart {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  will-change: transform;
}
.heart:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: animation 3.2s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) 0.5s infinite both alternate;
  animation: animation 3.2s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) 0.5s infinite both alternate;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(45deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(45deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(45deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(45deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(45deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(45deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(45deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(45deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%);
  background-position: 12px 17px, 37px 1px, 3px 36px, 33px 27px, 1px 38px, 12px 18px, 39px 20px, 34px 33px, 26px 9px, 17px 30px, 21px 15px, 32px 34px, 30px 18px, 24px 35px, 18px 17px, 32px 21px, 33px 21px, 28px 7px, 13px 38px, 13px 20px, 26px 9px, 33px 32px, 16px 7px, 7px 11px, 38px 25px, 4px 25px, 34px 15px, 13px 33px, 32px 19px, 14px 11px, 28px 18px, 5px 8px, 5px 25px, 15px 14px, 30px 15px, 2px 14px, 23px 40px, 10px 37px, 34px 20px, 8px 18px, 32px 37px, 16px 7px, 23px 9px, 13px 32px, 33px 31px, 26px 3px, 31px 2px, 27px 40px, 23px 2px, 11px 8px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animation {
  50%, 100% {
    background-position: 10px 10px, 10px 10px, 5px 15px, 5px 15px, 10px 20px, 10px 20px, 15px 5px, 10px 10px, 10px 10px, 15px 15px, 10px 15px, 15px 20px, 15px 20px, 10px 25px, 15px 25px, 15px 10px, 15px 10px, 20px 15px, 20px 15px, 15px 20px, 15px 20px, 20px 25px, 20px 25px, 15px 30px, 20px 30px, 25px 10px, 20px 10px, 25px 15px, 20px 15px, 25px 20px, 25px 20px, 20px 25px, 20px 25px, 25px 30px, 20px 30px, 25px 5px, 30px 10px, 30px 10px, 25px 15px, 25px 15px, 30px 20px, 25px 20px, 30px 25px, 25px 25px, 30px 10px, 30px 10px, 35px 15px, 35px 15px, 30px 20px, 30px 20px;
  }
}
@keyframes animation {
  50%, 100% {
    background-position: 10px 10px, 10px 10px, 5px 15px, 5px 15px, 10px 20px, 10px 20px, 15px 5px, 10px 10px, 10px 10px, 15px 15px, 10px 15px, 15px 20px, 15px 20px, 10px 25px, 15px 25px, 15px 10px, 15px 10px, 20px 15px, 20px 15px, 15px 20px, 15px 20px, 20px 25px, 20px 25px, 15px 30px, 20px 30px, 25px 10px, 20px 10px, 25px 15px, 20px 15px, 25px 20px, 25px 20px, 20px 25px, 20px 25px, 25px 30px, 20px 30px, 25px 5px, 30px 10px, 30px 10px, 25px 15px, 25px 15px, 30px 20px, 25px 20px, 30px 25px, 25px 25px, 30px 10px, 30px 10px, 35px 15px, 35px 15px, 30px 20px, 30px 20px;
  }
}

span {
  display: inline-block
}
span:first-of-type {
  margin-right: 10px
}
span:last-of-type {
  margin-left: 40px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>About</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/about.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/heart.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                 <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="index.html">
                     <span class="name">Hello</span>
                     <span name="surname">World </span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#download">Download</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- About Section -->
    <section id="about" class="container content-section text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                <h2>Hi there!</h2>
                <p>Lore ipmaosdkfna;lskdnf;alksdnf;aklsjdf a;lsdkjf;alskdjf;alksdjf;alskdjfa;lskdjf;a.asfasdf</p>
                <p>
  <span>I</span><span class="heart"></span><span>code</span>
</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
             
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script>
        function collapseNavbar() {
                $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
        }

        $(window).scroll(collapseNavbar);
        $(document).ready(collapseNavbar);

        // jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
        $(function() {
            $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
                var $anchor = $(this);
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
                }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });

        // Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
        $('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
          if ($(this).attr('class') != 'dropdown-toggle active' && $(this).attr('class') != 'dropdown-toggle') {
            $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
          }
        });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

The heart should be displaying in the center. However, that isn't happening

EDIT: Updated post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can wrap the all text with a `p` (could be another tag) and each word with a `span`, with a few tweaks to your code here you go:

```css
body {
  background-color: #222;
}
.heart {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  will-change: transform;
}
.heart:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: animation 3.2s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) 0.5s infinite both alternate;
  animation: animation 3.2s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) 0.5s infinite both alternate;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(45deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(45deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(45deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(45deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(45deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(45deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(45deg, #eb7d7d 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #b31c1c 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #c91f1f 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(-135deg, #e45151 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(45deg, #e03b3b 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%), linear-gradient(135deg, #871515 6.2625%, transparent 6.2625%);
  background-position: 12px 17px, 37px 1px, 3px 36px, 33px 27px, 1px 38px, 12px 18px, 39px 20px, 34px 33px, 26px 9px, 17px 30px, 21px 15px, 32px 34px, 30px 18px, 24px 35px, 18px 17px, 32px 21px, 33px 21px, 28px 7px, 13px 38px, 13px 20px, 26px 9px, 33px 32px, 16px 7px, 7px 11px, 38px 25px, 4px 25px, 34px 15px, 13px 33px, 32px 19px, 14px 11px, 28px 18px, 5px 8px, 5px 25px, 15px 14px, 30px 15px, 2px 14px, 23px 40px, 10px 37px, 34px 20px, 8px 18px, 32px 37px, 16px 7px, 23px 9px, 13px 32px, 33px 31px, 26px 3px, 31px 2px, 27px 40px, 23px 2px, 11px 8px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animation {
  50%, 100% {
    background-position: 10px 10px, 10px 10px, 5px 15px, 5px 15px, 10px 20px, 10px 20px, 15px 5px, 10px 10px, 10px 10px, 15px 15px, 10px 15px, 15px 20px, 15px 20px, 10px 25px, 15px 25px, 15px 10px, 15px 10px, 20px 15px, 20px 15px, 15px 20px, 15px 20px, 20px 25px, 20px 25px, 15px 30px, 20px 30px, 25px 10px, 20px 10px, 25px 15px, 20px 15px, 25px 20px, 25px 20px, 20px 25px, 20px 25px, 25px 30px, 20px 30px, 25px 5px, 30px 10px, 30px 10px, 25px 15px, 25px 15px, 30px 20px, 25px 20px, 30px 25px, 25px 25px, 30px 10px, 30px 10px, 35px 15px, 35px 15px, 30px 20px, 30px 20px;
  }
}
@keyframes animation {
  50%, 100% {
    background-position: 10px 10px, 10px 10px, 5px 15px, 5px 15px, 10px 20px, 10px 20px, 15px 5px, 10px 10px, 10px 10px, 15px 15px, 10px 15px, 15px 20px, 15px 20px, 10px 25px, 15px 25px, 15px 10px, 15px 10px, 20px 15px, 20px 15px, 15px 20px, 15px 20px, 20px 25px, 20px 25px, 15px 30px, 20px 30px, 25px 10px, 20px 10px, 25px 15px, 20px 15px, 25px 20px, 25px 20px, 20px 25px, 20px 25px, 25px 30px, 20px 30px, 25px 5px, 30px 10px, 30px 10px, 25px 15px, 25px 15px, 30px 20px, 25px 20px, 30px 25px, 25px 25px, 30px 10px, 30px 10px, 35px 15px, 35px 15px, 30px 20px, 30px 20px;
  }
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%
}
span {
  display: inline-block
}
span:first-of-type {
  margin-right: 10px
}
span:last-of-type {
  margin-left: 40px
}
```

```html
<p class="absolute">
  <span>I</span><span class="heart"></span><span>code</span>
</p>
```

Comment: You sir, have made my day

Comment: Umm this worked for a specific case but it still isn't integrating well into my page. Could you have a look? I'll update the code in the question. You can check it from there

Comment: @bholagabbar better show me an online link, that won't be a good fit to help you, because there is too much non-relevant code

Comment: Umm I'm making my own website and that is the specific case I need it for. I've pickup up an online template yes but I've changed it significantly

Comment: I inspected your new code, you are missing this: `p {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%
}`

Comment: Yes if I add that, then my entire layout goes bonkers. Try that out and see. If you see the updated code, I have already defined *p {..}* Cam't something be done there

Comment: just create a class for that `p`, I'll update my answer. || @bholagabbar see updated answer

Comment: @bholagabbar have you seen my latest comment and updated answer?

Comment: I works but still shows up in the center of the page. That can't be adjusted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109487/discussion-between-dippas-and-bholagabbar).